# Javascript using match, splice and split gives error on splits is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a conversie of a zipcode adress `7711kt`.
First I am trying to match the zipcode with regex `var res = string.match(/\d{4}|[a-zA-Z]{2}\b/g);`That works and it also splits the 4 numbers and two letters.  after that I am using `var splits = res.slice(1);`to get only the letters in the array. That works fine, until I want to split them to. It gives me an error that the splits is not a function. This code should convert the letters to numbers. What am I doing wrong and what is the best solution?

```js
function convertAlphabet(letter){
  switch(letter){
    case 'A': console.log(0); break;
    case 'B': console.log(1); break;
    case 'C': console.log(2); break;
    case 'D': console.log(3); break;
    case 'E': console.log(4); break;
    case 'F': console.log(5); break;
    case 'G': console.log(6); break;
    case 'H': console.log(7); break;
    case 'I': console.log(8); break;
    case 'J': console.log(9); break;
    case 'K': console.log(10); break;
    case 'L': console.log(11); break;
    case 'M': console.log(12); break;
    case 'N': console.log(13); break;
    case 'O': console.log(14); break;
    case 'P': console.log(15); break;
    case 'Q': console.log(16); break;
    case 'R': console.log(17); break;
    case 'S': console.log(18); break;
    case 'T': console.log(19); break;
    case 'U': console.log(20); break;
    case 'V': console.log(21); break;
    case 'W': console.log(22); break;
    case 'X': console.log(23); break;
    case 'Y': console.log(24); break;
    case 'Z': console.log(25); break;
  }
}

var string = "7711KT";
var res = string.match(/\d{4}|[a-zA-Z]{2}\b/g);
var splits = res.slice(1);
var restart = splits.split(" ");
console.log(restart);
console.log(convertAlphabet(restart));
```

Comment: match returns an array.

Comment: Side note: That `switch` can be replaced with `if (letter >= "A" && letter <= "Z") { console.log(letter.charCodeAt(0) - 65); }` (If you **know** it will be in that range, you can leave the `if` off.)

Comment: Yes, then the slice gets 1 in the array and should convert this to two different strings, so the letters can be converted to numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting the words from your string, you can `split()` your string and use `array#map` to covert your alphabet into numerical values.

```js
function convertAlphabet(letter){
  if(letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z')
    return letter.charCodeAt(0) % 65;
  else if(letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z')
    return letter.charCodeAt(0) % 97;
  else
    return letter.charCodeAt(0);
}

var string = "7711KT";
var res = string.match(/\d{4}|[a-zA-Z]{2}\b/g);
var splits = res[1];
console.log(splits.split('').map(ch => convertAlphabet(ch)));
```

Comment: Yes, map returns a new array.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you mean

```js
var str = "7711KT";
str = str.replace(/([A-Z])/g, function(a, letter) {
  return '>'+(letter.charCodeAt(0) - 65)+'<'; // using "<>" to make it more visible
})
console.log(str)
```

Comment: didn't know we can callback function after regex pattern :) nice,, like it

Answer (score 0):

here is what you want
change your regular expression then its returns all matches

```js
function convertAlphabet(letter){
  switch(letter){
    case 'A': console.log(0); break;
    case 'B': console.log(1); break;
    case 'C': console.log(2); break;
    case 'D': console.log(3); break;
    case 'E': console.log(4); break;
    case 'F': console.log(5); break;
    case 'G': console.log(6); break;
    case 'H': console.log(7); break;
    case 'I': console.log(8); break;
    case 'J': console.log(9); break;
    case 'K': console.log(10); break;
    case 'L': console.log(11); break;
    case 'M': console.log(12); break;
    case 'N': console.log(13); break;
    case 'O': console.log(14); break;
    case 'P': console.log(15); break;
    case 'Q': console.log(16); break;
    case 'R': console.log(17); break;
    case 'S': console.log(18); break;
    case 'T': console.log(19); break;
    case 'U': console.log(20); break;
    case 'V': console.log(21); break;
    case 'W': console.log(22); break;
    case 'X': console.log(23); break;
    case 'Y': console.log(24); break;
    case 'Z': console.log(25); break;
  }
}

var string = "7711KT";
//var res = string.match(/\d{4}|[a-zA-Z]{2}\b/g);
var res = string.match(/([0-9]{4})([a-zA-z]{1}).*?/);
console.log(res);
//var splits = res.slice(1);
// var restart = splits.split(" ");
//console.log(restart);
convertAlphabet(res[2]);
```